# derivative of an implicitly given matrix function

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let $K,C,M$ be 3 $n \times n$ real regular matrices. Let $v_i, i = 1,...,k$ an orthonormal basis for a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and define $$V = [v_1, v_2, ...,v_k]$$
Let $F(\omega) = K + i \omega C- \omega^2 M$ and let $z(\omega)$ implicitly given by $$V^* F(\omega) V z(\omega) = V^* f$$
where $.^*$ is the conjugate transpose.
How can I calculate the derivative of $z(\omega)$ in $0$ ? The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the fact that the matrix is only given implicitely.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are $\omega$ and $f$ ? The product $V^*F(\omega)$ is not defined.

Comment: $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ and because $.*$ is the conjugate transpose size($V^*$) $= k \times n$ and the matrices$ K$, $C$ en $M$ are all $n \times n$ dimensional so I wonder what you mean by 'not defined'